# C++ Lista heterogênea

Tags: c++, vector

Há semanas tenho procurado na internet sobre listas (`vector`, `array`, `list`) heterogêneas em c++, porém, em todos os sites e fóruns, a resposta é a mesma: `boost::any`, mas eu queria uma forma de fazer em c++ puro. Desenvolvi isso:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <typeinfo>
#include <vector>

using namespace std; 
 //Compiler version g++ 6.3.0

 class any
 {
 public:
    auto get() {}
 };

 template<typename T>
 class anyTyped : public any
 {
 public:
    T val;

    anyTyped(T x)
    {
        val = x;
    }
    T get()
    {
        return val;
    }
 };

 class queue
 {
    vector<any*> x;
    int len = 0;

 public:
    queue()
    {
        x.resize(0);
    }

    template<typename T>
    void insert(T val)
    {
        any* ins = new anyTyped<T>(val);
        x.push_back(ins);
        len++;
    }
    int size()
    {
        return len;
    }

    auto& at(int idx)
    {
        return x[idx]->get();
    }
 };

 int main()
 {

    queue vec;

    vec.insert(5);     //int
    vec.insert(4.3);   //double
    vec.insert("txt"); //char*

    for (int i = 0; i < vec.size(); i++)
    {
        cout << vec.at(i);
    }

    return 0;
 }
```

Mas recebo o seguinte erro:

```
source_file.cpp: In member function 'auto& queue::at(int)':
source_file.cpp:55:23: error: forming reference to void
    return x[idx]->get();
                       ^
source_file.cpp: In function 'int main()':
source_file.cpp:70:9: error: no match for 'operator<<' (operand types are 'std::ostream {aka std::basic_ostream<char>}' and 'void')
    cout << vec.at(i);
    ~~~~~^~~~~~~~~~~~
```

Sei que o problema está no uso do `auto` como tipo de retorno, tanto em `auto get()` na classe `any`, quanto em `auto& at(int idx)` na classe `queue`, mas não sei como corrigir

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nesse caso você poderia eliminar o método `get()` e implementar o `operator<<` na classe `any` para jogar o conteúdo do `val` no `std::ostream`. Dessa maneira você não precisa se preocupar com tipos de retorno templatizados (sic) mas em contrapartida só suportaria um tipo de "output stream", no caso.

```
class any
{
public:
    friend ostream &
    operator<<(ostream &os, const any& a)
    {
        return a.output_to(os);
    }

    virtual ostream &output_to(ostream &os) const = 0;
};

template<typename T>
class anyTyped : public any
{
public:
    T val;

    anyTyped(T x)
    {
        val = x;
    }

    ostream &
    output_to(ostream &os) const
    {
        return os << val;
    }
};
```

Não se esqueça de corrigir o método `queue::at` para retornar uma referência para as variáveis de tipo `any`:

```
auto& at(int idx)
{
    return *x[idx];
}
```

PS: As variáveis inseridas em `queue` (instruções `vec.insert` na função `main()`) são dos tipos `double` e `const char *`, e não `float` e `string`.

Comment: O que significa o `const = 0` e `const` nas funções `output_to`?

Comment: Não é `const = 0`, mas sim `virtual ... = 0` (método virtual puro). O `const` ao final do método diz que ele não modificará nenhuma variável do objeto e pode ser utilizado em objetos referenciados também como `const`. Veja https://stackoverflow.com/questions/751681/meaning-of-const-last-in-a-c-method-declaration